# Все элементы из ToggleGroup в виде GameObject

Tags: c#, unity3d

Из `ToggleGroup` мне нужно получить все элементы, но не в виде `Toggle` а в виде `GameObject`. Какие варианты решения есть для этой задачи?

Comment: `[экземпляр Togle].gameObject` не работает?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Вы про [это](http://prntscr.com/opmb6m)?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский если надо имя `ToggleGroup`-а `ToolsGroup`

Comment: По методам `ToggleGroup` вижу только возможность получить активные `Toggle`. Не знаю, как перебрать все, включенные в эту группу. А что за квадратные скобки у Вас в скриншоте? В моем комментарии выше под `[экземпляр Togle]` подразумевается имя переменной типа Toggle, полученной, допустим, из ToggleGrup.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский ваш вариант работает но только как вы уже сказали не для всех.

Comment: С `Toggle` работать не доводилось, с их группами тем более. Пока в голову приходит разве что в какой-то момент времени создавать список всех `Toggle` на сцене и когда надо сверять их поле `group` с необходимым `ToggleGroup`

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский пока нет ответа на мой вопрос я это и пытаюсь сделать но это сильно замедлит меня.

Comment: @Alt_F4 насколько часто этот метод будет вызываться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Короткий ответ

Это невозможно, потому что список всех Toggle приватный (и это логично для полей, но публичного доступа к этому списку нет), [в чем мы можем убедиться из исходного кода](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/2019.1/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/ToggleGroup.cs):

```
public class ToggleGroup : UIBehaviour
{
    ... 
    private List<Toggle> m_Toggles = new List<Toggle>();
    ...
}
```

### Длинный ответ

Это возможно благодаря рефлексии, имя поля мы уже знаем, осталось только написать, к примеру, расширение для `ToggleGroup`'а:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public static class ToggleGroupExtensions {
    private static FieldInfo _toggleListMember;

    public static IList<Toggle> GetToggles(this ToggleGroup grp) {
        if (_toggleListMember == null) {
            _toggleListMember = typeof(ToggleGroup).GetField("m_Toggles", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (_toggleListMember == null)
                throw new Exception("Reflection error, Unity ToggleGroup source code might have been changed");
        }
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<Toggle>((IList<Toggle>)_toggleListMember.GetValue(grp));
    }

    public static List<GameObject> GetTogglesGameobjects(this ToggleGroup grp) {
        var toggles = grp.GetToggles();
        var gameObjects = new List<GameObject>(toggles.Count);
        gameObjects.AddRange(toggles.Select(x => x.gameObject));
        return gameObjects;
    }
}
```

### P.S.

Вся логика рефлексии кэшируется в `FieldInfo`, так что этот подход не сильно отличен по производительности от прямого доступа к полю объекта класса, да и альтернатив в данном случае нет.

И да, из `GetToggles` **важно** возвращать именно `ReadOnlyCollection`, потому что изменение этого списка извне приведет к ошибкам логики `ToggleGroup`'а.